# Use PHPDocumentor to create an Eclipse Library

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

I have an unusual request,

I'm working on PHP 5.3, my IDE is Eclipse and I need help setting a file like the one that comes in default with the php functions, so I can use it for code completion and I can have the documentation on hover.

So basically, I have a library, which I want to pull the declarations for everything (function, classes, etc) and the PHPDoc block, and use them to create a new file, which will be added as a library on Eclipse on the include path. Anyone knows an automatic way to do it?

EDIT: To explain a bit better what I want to do. I want to run a script that will do almost what PHPDoc does, but instead of creating a set of html files after load a file, it will create a copy of the php file which only has the declarations and comments. So that file can be given to the programmers, instead of the full library with source-code.

I though about using the ReflecationClass, by including each file, check the defined class\functions and then writing the new file, but that means that all the includes\requires need to happen in order, something I can't guarantee

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this counts as "automatic", but what you describe sounds like it can be roughly accomplished by having this library itself as an open Eclipse project.  If your "new code" is in a separate Eclipse project, then you want to list your library project in the new project's Include Path configuration.

In the "PHP Include Path" config popup for your *new* project, click "Add" and select the library project (it will only be visible here if it is also "open").  You can choose whether or not it should come before the new project on the include path or not by moving things around in the Order tab.  I tend to keep my current project listed first, then dependencies afterward, just in case any of my new project's classes take precedence over same name classes in the dependency projects.

An added benefit to this is that when you open your new project, any referenced projects in the Include Path configuration will automatically be opened too.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, since I do not have access to the source code of that library. What I want exactly is to run a script similar to what PHPDoc does, but instead of creating html files, I will simply create a php file with the declarations and comments.

Comment: If you don't have access to the source, I'm not sure that anything could be run over it to parse out code elements.  Without the source, I don't see any way except to manually write out the API itself by hand into a "library" project.  You're effectively talking about having to reverse-engineer the API just to be able to see the API you want to use.

Comment: Ok, based on your question edit... *you* have the source, but want to _distribute_ only a PHP file containing empty declarations, so that your *users* could then use my Eclipse include path answer?

A potential idea would be for you to write a custom output template for phpDocumentor... but a tokenizer or reflection trick might also give you what you want.

If the programmers are writing code against this library, but are not allowed to have the library in hand, I take they cannot test their code?

Comment: They can as the code is on the development servers. It is a bit tricky. The reflection hit the problem I said, I will see about the PHPDocumentor template and the tokenizer. Thanks